# Cross-browser alternative method of performing text reflection + gradient (like -webkit-box-reflect)

Tags: php, jquery, image-processing, typography

I'd like to achieve the effect of -webkit-box-reflect in other browsers also (ie mirrored text with a gradient applied).  Eg.

```
.textreflection {
    -webkit-box-reflect: below -5px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), to(rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4))); 
 }
```

I'm open to server side (PHP, ie. happy to generate images server side to replace text) and client side (Javascript - jQuery) solutions.

I've tried a couple of jQuery plugins but they either didn't look right or didn't work properly with all font sizes ([FontEffect](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fonteffect), and jquery.textreflection).

Any ideas how I can achieve this effect in an elegant cross-browser way, please?

PS. I'd also be interested if anyone knows of any HTML5/Canvas solutions that I can keep in mind for future reference (I can't use it in this instance but would like to have a look anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few solutions that work with images, but I haven't tested with text:

- [Reflection.js](http://cow.neondragon.net/stuff/reflection/)
- [CSS3 flip reflection](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-flip-gallery.html)
- [Reflex.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/reflex/)

Comment: Will have a look at those and evaluate them... Thank you.